# Custom Widget to extends Widget or use Widget as member?

Tags: flutter, widget, member, extends

I want to create a Custom Widget, I am not sure which one is better for my purpose, does anyone give suggestion?
First way:

```
class ListItem extends LisTile {
  final TileType tileType;
  ...
}
```

Second way:

```
class ListItem {
  final TileType tileType;
  final ListTile tile;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strongly recommended to use composition (this has-a that) rather than inheritance (this is-a that).  Otherwise, you are tightly coupled with everything the Flutter team does to change upcoming releases that isn't necessarily part of the public interface.